# Student comments from meetings frequently overreacted to by senior 'management'

Tags: united-kingdom, interpersonal-issues, administration, workplace

I've worked at several UK institutions over the past 10 years and one aspect that consistently raises my eyebrows is the reaction to student-staff liaison meetings* from senior members of the team. Often, these meetings are merely an opportunity for the 'representative' to voice their **own** concerns and are clearly, obviously, not representative. Yet, time after time, when a far fetched and often untrue complaint/comment is made in one of these meetings, senior staff go into full meltdown and start firing off perplexing and demotivating e-mails asking for things to be fixed because the students are unhappy. The simple matter is, as previously stated, these are often not representative views and the sample size is one: the person who said it.

In any other context, a sample size of one would be immediately disregarded by those with only rudimentary scientific knowledge. No sound conclusion could ever be drawn from that sample. Yet, if this sample happens to be one student in the context of a 'staff-student liaison' meeting then it appears to be absolute fact to senior 'management'.

My question is for fellow academics from across the world, do you have this nonsense to deal with? What do you tell 'management' if they ask you to change based on comments from a single source? Am I being too touchy about it?

I am a lecturer at a UK institution.

*These meetings are usually bi-yearly where student 'representatives' voice any matters arising on their degree

---

For the those thinking "Jeez, this guy gets a lot of bad comments". I have not once been on the receiving end of this but I know good colleagues lose sleep over it.

I also see the benefits of these meetings, I do not wish for them to be scrapped.

Comment: Who are the student's "representatives"? Are they just any student the department can get on the hallway at that time or are they somehow elected (from a student council or association)?

Comment: They are 'elected' (often by default, in my experience) students within the current cohort and are meant to represent student views. While a nice idea, rarely do these students represent more than themselves or their own, small social circle of friends.

Comment: It seems that the real issue here is that the student representative is not (in your view) accurately representing the position of their constituency as a whole. The route to addressing this lies in trying to increase accountability: do the students have an opportunity to meet and provide input for their representative to present? Are the student body aware of what their representative is saying on their behalf (e.g. are meeting minutes circulated)? I would focus on fixing the real problem, rather than encouraging management to ignore concerns apparently presented through the proper channels.

Comment: So, they are elected (no quotations here). And if the students are not complaining about the representatives and what they bring up during the student-staff liaison meetings, they probably either do not care, agree with the representatives or do not even know the meeting even exists.

Comment: Also, having some sort of survey so that students can make criticism is also a good option, but that usually requires moderation (as some very rude criticism can be made). And that comments moderation would probably be well done by... students representatives.

Comment: @jDAQ We do run module-based surveys whereby students can leave anonymous feedback to staff and more often than not, those criticisms levied in these meetings are not brought up by the vast majority of students.

Comment: @avid You should look to make some of those comments an answer as you raise several interesting points.

Comment: Do the student representatives have access to those surveys? So those comments are "not brought up by the vast majority of students" but they are by a smaller group? Do they happen to be more serious/grave than the common feedback/complaint?

Comment: @jDAQ Yes, survey results are released to all students (just to clarify, representatives are just normal students with the role of 'rep'). "Do they happen to be more serious/grave than the common feedback/complaint?" I'm sure there have been instances, but not from what I've seen. Usually complaints that could have been easily rectified if the students just spoke to the staff member (e.g. "I didn't understand X").  My question is really trying to focus on the overreaction of 'management' based on flimsy evidence, I'm not trying to stomp on student feedback/comments which I do value.

Comment: "I also see the benefits of these meetings, I do not wish for them to be scrapped." What are the benefits, in your opinion? I'm asking because you also state, "these meetings are merely an opportunity for the 'representative' to voice their own concerns and are clearly, obviously, not representative." If these are the only kinds of comments put forth, I can't really see any benefits. But if there are actually useful comments made, how are you distinguishing these from the "bad" comments?

Comment: @richard I suppose I appreciate the notion of the meeting and there are sometimes constructive comments that are not just baseless complaints. However, more often than not they are hijacked as an opportunity for reps to, seemingly, use them to voice their individual concerns under the guise of being representative. Comments such as "We didn't get any help for assignment X" when it's clear they did get help. This is evidence in module forum discussions, recorded lectures and e-mails. Yet management opt to not look at any of this evidence and just take the student's word on it.

Comment: Not wanting to do a fully fleshed out answer yet, but it is all related to the NSS (Nation Student Survey) results and the perceived effect of the universities ranking that stems from those results....

Comment: This question needs rewriting to be a single question, without the rant and survey aspects.

Answer (score 4):

[Converting a comment to an answer at the invitation of @hueblue...]

I feel you are focussing on the wrong part of the issue here. It does not make sense to encourage 'management' to ignore the student representative's views; inevitably this will just create problems and bad feeling in the future, when students get the impression that their input is ignored.

The real issue is that (at least in your perception) the student representatives are not doing their job properly: they are using their position as a platform for their personal views, rather than those of the student body at large. It seems to me that this is what you should aim to address. Some things to consider:

- How well do the student body understand the role played by their representative(s)?
- How are elections handled? Are they treated as important, or an annoyance to be dispatched as quickly as possible in the first lecture of the year?
- Is the student body aware of the issues that are being discussed in meetings attended by their representative(s)? Do they know when meetings are due to take place?
- Are students reminded to send comments to their representative(s) in advance of relevant meetings?
- Is there a clear, well-advertised, equitable opportunity for the student body to get together and discuss any issues and concerns they have with the representative(s)?
- Do students have any way of knowing what their representative(s) said in meetings? Are minutes or summaries circulated to the student body at large?

I suspect that at present, the answer to most of the above questions is 'No' - certainly that was the case when I was a student. If you can change some of them to 'Yes', you will probably see a marked improvement in the quality of representation.

Comment: I disagree, because these factors should not be under faculty control.  They should be under student control.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I agree, up to a point. But faculty play a role in setting the culture here. If they give students the impression that the representative role is unimportant, then it will be treated as unimportant, and vice versa. Moreover, given that committee business is typically run by faculty, things like publicising agendas and minutes (versus labelling them 'confidential') is very much for faculty to decide.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist To give a concrete example, I certainly remember a lecturer on the first day of the year saying with great irritation "I've been told to get you to elect a class rep. Who's going to do it? Come on, someone put their hand up... right, you. Any objections? Done. Now we can get on with class." Clearly this does not lead to students feeling that the process has any great importance.

Answer (score 2):

In our UK, Russel group, STEM department the Staff-Student liason structures seem to work well.

We have a staff-student committee that is attended by any staff member involved in teaching and representatives from every group of students in the department. The students are there as elected representatives, but obviously they bring their own experiences to the table.

The students can and often do raise worries about thing in this meeting and often an explanation of why things are this way is offered, the students are told that the matter will be investigated and the results presented at the next meeting. This usually results in either an explanation, or a small tweak to how things are setup, or an apology that something went wrong. The students are almost always satisfied with this. Part of this is that those in charge are old hands and are very good at making the students feel listened to, without panicking and deciding everything has to change.

We also have a smaller number of student representatives on the Department's teaching committee, which is the departments ultimate policy making body with regards to teaching. Students are there to express their views on matters of policy, and not to raise specific issues. For example, we recently discussed changing our structure in the 3rd year from 10 credit modules to 20 credit ones, thinking the students would prefer this as it would mean fewer exams, but it turns out that the students unanimously preferred the 10 credit system.

Neither of these forums is the right place for a serious complaint about a specific member of staff, and we have a proper complaints procedure to handle this.

In general this all works well. The students are on the whole pretty happy with how things are run, and in return rarely raise vexatious or petty complaints.